# Question about HSA: on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, questions

I've a question about the tax status of a refund of a payment originally made from an HSA. (Health Savings Acct., US-based.) I suspect it may not be on-topic here, but saw a number of other tax-related questions and wondered if it might be worth a shot.

**Would such a question be on-topic here?**

---

A few have weighed-in as being on-topic. Whether or not it is, [here it is](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/56860/35619).

Comment: Yes, questions about how individuals use HSAs would be on topic because they are about personal expenses, income, and taxes. I'm wondering, though, why did you suspect it would be not on topic?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea because the full question isn't about how much to allocate, or what the benefits analysis should be, but rather the tax implications of a *refund*--the full question I'll post later today. Seemed like it might be an edge case, so I figured I'd check first.

Comment: That seems very much on topic. Tax related questions (for individuals) are definitely on topic)

Comment: I would say that the tax implications are *more* on topic (or, more appropriate) than "questions about how much to allocate" - decisions about how much and such tend towards opinion and to be less answerable.  Tax implications are *squarely* in our wheelhouse.

Answer (score 7):

There are some similar questions:

- [Can return fees be reimbursed from an HSA?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/46864/can-return-fees-be-reimbursed-from-an-hsa),
- [How do I correct an HSA distribution when I was refunded by a health provider?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/47303/how-do-i-correct-an-hsa-distribution-when-i-was-refunded-by-a-health-provider)
- [Health Savings Account Insurance Reimbursement](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/43880/health-savings-account-insurance-reimbursement)
- [Can I get a rebate after using my HSA?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15866/can-i-get-a-rebate-after-using-my-hsa/15870#15870)

Look them over and see if they answer your question.

If you do ask a question, to be able to answer we would have to know:

- is the payment and refund in the same tax year?
- do you still have access to the HSA?
- are you still under the HSA?

Comment: I've posted the question, linked in my OP. Thanks for helping me find others and flesh out mine.